# LDAP multiple values attributes filter

Tags: email, postfix, ldap, openldap

Can't find same question, but I think it's regular issue. I have LDAP user:

```
dn: uid=alise,ou=peoples,dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
cn: alise
sn: alise
uid: alise
userPassword: {SCHEME}password
mail: alise@domain1.tld
mail: alise@domain2.tld
mailAlias: bill@domain1.tld
mailAlias: bill@domain2.tld
```

I need to return mail attribute, but filtered by domain. For example if I search:

```
ldapsearch -xLLL -b ou=peoples,dc=withsound,dc=ru '(mailAlias=bill@domain1.tld)' mail
```

I get:

```
dn: uid=alise,ou=peoples,dc=acme,dc=com
mail: alise@domain1.tld
mail: alise@domain2.tld
```

But I need something like:

```
ldapsearch -xLLL -b ou=peoples,dc=withsound,dc=ru '(mailAlias=bill@domain1.tld)' mail=*domain1.tld


dn: uid=alise,ou=peoples,dc=acme,dc=com
mail: alise@domain1.tld
```

I can't simply use *| grep domain1.tld* cause I use LDAP search in Postfix

I really don't want to separate user and make only one email field...

Answer (score 4):

A search term like this should help:

```
(&(mailAlias=bill@domain1.tld)(mail=*domain1.tld))
```

LDAP search terms get combined like this:

```
(Operator(filter)(filter)(filter)...)
```

with `Operator` being `&` (AND), `|` (OR) and `!` (NOT).

Comment: Unfortunately it returns 2 value. Cause one of the value of "mail" attribute return TRUE and we required "mail" attribute as a result =( I found there's no option to return 1 value of multi-valued attribute =(

Comment: If Sven's tip does not work for your needs, then you'll need to script this with your favourite language and create a Postfix map file.